# Change the size of UIImageView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie in Swift And Xcode.

Is there any clean way to change `UIImageView` Size placed inside a `UITableViewCell`?

This is my TableView, I want to align left label correctly [image]

Comment: Can you please share the code or screenshot for the UITableViewCell xib ?

Comment: Give the imageView a fixed width and set its property to aspect fit.

Comment: It better to Fix Image width in this scenario so `UILabel` will automatically align from left.

Comment: Give it fixed constraints for width and height and set the content mode of the image to scale to fill. The image will scale itself in order to use the entire area of the imageview and all the images will have the same size. Please note that doing that maybe you change the aspect ratio of the images and it could look not good.

Comment: @Kuldeep i want to do that, but can't changing Image width from swift

Comment: @sateesh https://prnt.sc/ll5hkp

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
cell.imageView!.image = image
```

with

```
cell.imageView?.image = image.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
```

Add this `UIImageView` extension to the project.

```
extension UIImage {
    func scaleImage(toSize newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        var newImage: UIImage?
        let newRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height).integral
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let cgImage = self.cgImage {
            context.interpolationQuality = .high
            let flipVertical = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: newSize.height)
            context.concatenate(flipVertical)
            context.draw(cgImage, in: newRect)
            if let img = context.makeImage() {
                newImage = UIImage(cgImage: img)
            }
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        return newImage
    }
}
```

**Reason** for the error in your code is `UITableViewCell` is assigning the various size for `UIImageView` based on the image size inside it. In addition to I've adjusted the image to specific size so that it can fit to imageView content in `UITableViewCell`.

**Note:**
Please don't post the screenshots of the code as it does not help to others to copy it from the question and which attracts -ve voting as well. However, you can post the screenshots for XIBs, Storyboards and for Simulation errors.

Comment: can you tell me how to decrease space between flag and table left edge?

Comment: The distance between leading space of imageView and cell left edge is 20, which is defined by the tableView itself. So, we can't change it. However, we can make a custom UITableViewCell to achieve the requirement what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the width of the `UIImageView` and set its contentMode to `.scaleAspectFit`.

```
myImageView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

However, if you are using the storyboard, you can set these properties there itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stack view or a view with proportianal constraint to the relavite view in your cell xib. In this way the portion of the flag will be always the same.

Otherwise, if you want to do it quickly, you can contraint the leading of the label to the cell view and not with the flag. It's a litte bit dirtier but it should work.

Comment: i want to do it from swift